# scala + spark: serialize a task for recommendations

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, recommendation-engine

I've been working with Scala + Spark and the [Movie Recommendation with MLib](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html#recommending-movies-for-you) tutorial.

After obtaining my predictions I need the top 3 items per user.

```
val predictions = 
  model.predict(usersProducts).map { case Rating(user, product, rate) =>
  (user, product, rate)
}
```

I've tried this:

```
def myPrint(x:(Int, Int, Double)) = println(x._1 + ":" + x._2 + " - " +x._3)

predictions.collect().sortBy(- _._3).groupBy(_._1).foreach( t2 => t2._2.take(3).foreach(myPrint) )
```

( _.1 is user, _.2 is item, _.3 is rate)

I had to add the "collect()" method to make it work, but I can't serialize this task.
By the way, I added the myPrint method because I don't know how to obtain a collection or map from the last line.

Any idea to make it serializable?

Any idea to get a collection/map from last line?

If I can't do it better, in myPrint I will write in a database and make commit after 1000 insert.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure that all the computations are done in RDDs by slightly modifying your approach:

```
predictions.sortBy(- _.rating).groupBy(_.user)
  .flatMap(_._2.take(3)).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

A task that calls a method has to serialize the object containing the method. Try using a function value instead:

```
val myPrint: ((Int, Int, Double)) => Unit = x => ...
```

You don't want the `collect()` at the start, that defeats the whole point of using Spark.

I don't understand what you're saying about "get a collection/map". `.take(3)` already returns a collection.

Comment: this don't resolved my problem. I removed the collect and used your function but spark keeps saying that the Task is not serializable, but thanks for the tip about the use of the function value

Comment: What's your exact error? It may be coming from earlier in your program, given that the task was not serializable even when you had the `collect()` in there.

Comment: The exception said something like:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
...

Comment: So you're trying to ship the context around, which yeah, won't work. I really don't think it's the code you posted that's giving you the problem. Note that RDDs are lazy so an error can come from something several lines back.

Answer (score 0):

After read the answer of **lmm** and do some research I resolved my problem this way:

First, I begun to work with a Rating object instead of Tuples:

```
val predictions = model.predict(usersProducts)
```

Then I defined the function value as follows, now I do here the "take":

```
def myPrint: ((Int, Iterable[Rating])) => Unit = x => x._2.take(3).foreach(println)
```

So, now I mix everything this way:

```
predictions.sortBy(- _.rating).groupBy(_.user).foreach(myPrint)
```